# Three notification set in a broadcastreceiver

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-alarms

I have set three alarm at different hour, now I want to set three different notification that are shown when the alarm fire.

This is my `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
                    0, notificationIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("E' ora di colazione!")
            .setContentText("Cosa c'è per colazione?")
            .setSound(alarmSound)
            .setLights(Color.BLUE, 1000, 500)
            .setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000})
            .setAutoCancel(true);

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build()); 
}
```

This is my alarm set code:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), MyReceiver.class);
if(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) == null){
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 0, myIntent,0);
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
}
```

Comment: so what is happening ? Is notification thing not changing when alarm goes off or there is an issue with alarm not getting fired.

Comment: @Napolean no, actually as you can see I set only one notification, I want to know how I can set multiple notification in one broadcastreceiver

Comment: send some extra(different for each of three time) in the Intent using intent.putExtra and then inside onReceive() do intent.getExtra() and based on upon these values create/launch diff notification

Comment: @Napolean I tried your solution but it doesn't work, after the first notification is shown, the second notification doesn't replace the previous but is added to the other, so I have two notification displayed and not only one